# In the Fetch API, where does the response object come from?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm learning about the Fetch API and was wondering about the following:

```
// The fetch's `then` gets a Response instance back
fetch('someurl')
    .then(function(responseObj) {
        console.log('status: ', responseObj.status);
    });
```

Is the response object being returned from fetch('someurl')? I'm slightly confused when it says that 'The fetch's `then` gets a Response instance back'. Thanks!

Comment: "`fetch()` returns a *`Promise`* that *resolves* to the `Response`." - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: The browser (or whatever platform is supporting `fetch()`)  builds the response object.

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading the MDN entry on `Promise` objects.  They are crucial to modern javascript development: [MDN on Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)